# Visual Studio 2015 jQuery intellisense not working

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

So I created a Visual Studio 2015 empty ASP.net Core application and tried to add jQuery using bower, but it isn't picking up the intellisense for jQuery... It is showing a warning saying that "Intellisense was unable to determine an accurate completion list..."  JavaScript intellisense is still working just not the usual intellisense I would get after typing $.

I am using jquery 3.1.1 in bower set up and read that I need to downgrade.  Is that still the case?

Comment: Give the screenshots of your Scripts folder and _reference.js file (inside Scripts folder).

Comment: Did you look at the other questions on this topic? It is asked a lot.

Comment: There is no Scripts folder - maybe you are referring to older version to asp.net?

Yes - I did search prior to posting and is why I asked if downgrading the jquery version is "still" the only option. Honestly with the lack of answers I thought it maybe something other that the jquery version being 3.1.1

Comment: Not sure about ASP.NET Core, but I had a similar issue after installing the latest version of jQuery using Bower for a ASP.NET MVC 5 project, after removing the old jQuery files I noticed intellisense went away. Looking in to it, Bower didn't provide a new jquery-?.??.>.intellisense.js file, but reinserting the old file jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js and renaming it jquery-.intellisense.js re-enabled intellisense - but obviously not an up to date version. Not sure where to get the latest versions from, I suspect NuGet will have it.

Comment: we need more answers to this! it's very frustrating and the one answer doesnt help!

Answer (score 6):

I'm using VS 2015 and MVC 5 and was having this issue. I tried all the above and nothing worked.

I then when into

> Tool -> Options -> JavaScript -> Intellisense -> References

and added the

> jquery-1.9.1.intellisense.js

file. Worth mentioning I copied this file from my local project to the `C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Javascript\References folder`

I restarted VS and went back into my view and still didn't have intellisense for `jQuery`.

Then in my view above my script section I changed my jquery reference from the .min copy to the full and the intellisense started to work right away

Comment: There might also be *-vsdoc.js files to reference.

Answer (score -5):

1. Close your Visual Studio and restart again to check if it works or
   not.
2. If not work, restart your laptop.
3. If still not work, re-install
       your Visual Studio.

Comment: thanks but I tried all that before posting of course.

Comment: Do you have other laptop to try it? or your friends laptop to try?

Comment: you know how long visual studio takes to install?:)  - once without success is enough.  Also, all the other intellisense are working so I am narrowing it to jquery references and not Visual Studio itself.

Comment: this is a terrible solution. there are many other things you can try before something as drastic and time consuming as "reinstall vs". like literally anything else.

Comment: re-install VS ?? it can affect the work flow , you aware about it ?

Comment: And If re-installing doesn't work should I buy a new laptop?