# Radiobuttons showing up as lines in Visual C# .NET MVC webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, javascript-intellisense

I am trying to create a webpage in Visual Studio 2017 .NET using MVC. I have inserted 3 `radiobuttons` but instead of showing up as such, they are only coming as lines, and they are not select-able either. I tried running the same project on another computer and faced the same issue. The code is given below.

```
<div id="SubjectType">
    Core:<input type="radio" name="Subjects" value="1" /><br />
    PE:<input type="radio" name="Subjects" value="2" /><br />
    OE:<input type="radio" name="Subjects" value="3" /><br />
</div>
```

It is a .cshtml page.

I also tried using `@Html.RadioButton` and `@Html.RadioButtonFor` to no avail. Upon further digging, I opened the Google Chrome developer console while running the application and found the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: intellisense is not defined at jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js:15 (anonymous) @ jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js:15

I tried following the answers given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089146/visual-studio-2015-jquery-intellisense-not-working) but could not find a References subsection in the Tools window.

[This is a screenshot. 'Core', 'PE', and 'OE' are supposed to be in the form of radiobuttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcOKF.png)

I don't really know what to make of any of this. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong where you're looking. It works for me. I'd look into where Jquery is getting declared, looks like the error is around there. Maybe remove all unnecessary code in the view you don't need

Comment: There may be jquery error, it is nothing to do with jquery not being loaded and you have used html code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your id="SubjectType" is problem can you show what is your code about SubjectType?