# JQuery IntelliSense is not showing the right items in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, intellisense

The IntelliSense in the javascript editor in Visual Studio 2015 is not showing the correct items instead, it is showing everything that is related or not related to Jquery!

[image: JQuery IntelliSense problem]

I have tried to follow those steps [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089146/visual-studio-2015-jquery-intellisense-not-working), but it didn't solve the problem.

I am using Jquery 2.1.0

Comment: I know this isn't strictly helping, but JS intellisense in VS is a mess. I just turn it off as it's more of a hindrance than a help.

Comment: If you create a new asp.net web application, does this issue persists or not? I tried to create a Empty asp.net web application and use nuget to install the latest Jquery 3.1.1, create a new *.js file and drag the jquery-3.1.1.js into this *.js file and the intellisense works fine, please check this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgyxIuDOl7fjfdly5. Make sure your current *.js file can access/invoke the jquery-x.x.x.js, if your application is asp.net web forms or mvc, there should have a file _references.js includes your js file and the JQuery reference links to make them "know" each other